# "for which 'blah blah'" vs. "which 'blah blah' for"

Tags: prepositions, word-order, sentence-ends, hypercorrection, pied-piping

When is it appropriate to use "for which" instead of "which .. for"?

e.g. (talking about webpages)

> This method is useful for deprecated pages **for which** users have made bookmarks

vs

> This method is useful for deprecated pages **which** users have made bookmarks **for**

My instinct is that both sentences are semantically the same. The first example seems a little archaic, and it seems to clash with my prior use of "for". However, the second example doesn't seem to emphasis that the bookmark is for the deprecated page.

Is there any meaningful difference? Which should I prefer, and it what other circumstances should I use one over the other?

Thanks for reading